# Sub Segment data for Hot Spot Analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hot-spot

I have some crime data in a point file for the whole united states.  I would like to run a hot spot analysis on the data in arcgis 10.4 using the Hot Spot Analysis tool.  Instead of running it for the whole united states, I have a CBSA/MSA field which of which I would further like to segment the hotspot analysis to account for these changes in political boundary.

Is this possible to do this with this tool without having to split the US up into these MSA/CBSA sub categories?  I cannot seem to find any information on the web on how this maybe done.

Answer (score 2):

I would try running your analysis in Model Builder. That will allow you to use an iterator to run the analysis using each of your CBSA/MSA boundaries as the Bounding Polygon in the Optimized Hot Spot Analysis tool. If your political boundaries are features in one shapefile, use Iterate Feature Selection. If they are separate shapefiles in a directory, use Iterate Feature Classes.

[image]

Alternatively, if your crime data point layer includes the CBSA/MSA as an attribute of each point, you can instead Iterate over Feature Selection using your point data as the input.

[image]

Either way you go, you'll want to name the output of the Hot Spot Analysis tool something like %Value%_Hot_spots.shp so the output files take on the name of the selected political boundaries and do not overwrite each other. The %Value% operator in the output name is necessary to make sure the Iterator runs correctly.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark the question as solved. Thanks!